# ELF x86 - Why is return address pushed twice?

Tags: disassembly, x86, elf, stack

I reverse an ELF x86, and I would like to understand why the return address is pushed again on the stack? It should be already present there.

```
main:
lea    ecx, [esp+0x4 {argc}]
and    esp, 0xfffffff0
push   dword [ecx-0x4 {__return_addr}] {var_4}
push   ebp, {var_8}
mov    ebp, esp
push   edi {var_c}
push   ecx {argc} {var_10}
sub    esp, 0xb0
mov    eax, dword [ecx+0x4 {argv}]
mov    dword [ebp-0x9c {var_a4}], eax
mov    eax, dword [gs:0x14]
mov    dword [ebp-0xc {var_14}], eax
xor    eax, eax {0x0}
cmp    dword [ecx {argc}], 0x2
je     0x80485ae
...
```

Comment: In which lines is this happening?

Comment: I guess this is on the `push [ecx-0x4] var_4`. As we are in x86-32 `eip` is not directly callable.

Comment: What compiler is giving this code ? It looks like it is changing the return address of the function from the inside of the function. It is a breach in all the ABI that I know, so it must be either a very specific function (as `__libc_start_main()`) or an obfuscation technique to workaround recursive traversal disassembly technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It **was** present on the stack before `and esp, 0xfffffff0` instruction that aligns the stack to 16 bytes. This instruction doesn't erase the data that was previously at `esp` (so `ecx-4` still points to the return address), but stack pointer points now to possibly different value than at the begining of the function. So there is a need to push the return value (`[ecx-4]`) on the stack so that `esp` points to the return address instead of some garbage data.

For instance, assume that previous `esp` value was `0x11111118`. Then the function return address is located at `esp` (i.e. equals `[esp]`). But after the `and` operation, `esp` now equals `0x11111110`, so the function return address is at `esp+8` address, which is not on the stack (actually **below** it) and `esp` now points to some other data, which definitely isn't the function return address. But we know that `ecx-4` points to that address (since `ecx` = `0x11111118+4`=`0x1111111C`), so we push `[ecx-4]` on the stack, so that `esp` now points to it.