# Why won't IDA let me name this variable?

Tags: ida

I went to stack view and named it counter, and now it appears at the top of my function, although it didn't until I named it. 
[image]

The name didn't propagate over to the program, as you can see in the mov instruction in this block.

[image]

Comment: IDA doesn't look like it's resolving stack variable references. Try to right click on one of the `[esp+XXh]` operands and see if you can select variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `[esp+5Ch]` is not the value of counter. The numbers next to the names of variables / arguments on stack are offsets with respect to `ebp`.

So `[ebp-5Ch]` is the value of the variable counter.

And since the variables are accessed via `esp`, not `rbp` and there is stack aligning instruction (`and esp, FFFFFFF0`), I *guess* IDA is not sure if that instruction will change `esp` or not, so it won't rename `[esp + offset]` to an argument or variable, since `esp` could have different values modulo `16` (i.e. `and esp, FFFFFFF0` will not change `esp` if `esp = 11111110`, but will change it when `esp = 11111118`) and thus different values with respect to `ebp`.

Comment: Never seen stack alignment instruction before. Is it common?

Comment: It will be called almost in every `main` function while compiling with GCC. See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21414/elf-x86-why-is-return-address-pushed-twice/21417#21417

Comment: Yeh I do reversing on Windows. Thanks, though